# How to lock rotation of instance object created by array and curve modifier along curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I want make stairs follow along curve but stay their rotation as it is. I tried lock rotation constrain and made the curve Twist method Z up but still same. [image]

thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Unfortunately, it's not clear what the problem is. Could you please show your node tree, or share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com? Thank you!

Comment: in that case, don't use array along curve for the object itself, use if for a single vertex, and parent your stair step to this vertex

Comment: Thank you for answers people. Instancing solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this by using instances.

1. Create the step of the stair, a curve, and a mesh object which contains only a single vert at its origin
2. Make the Vert the parent of the Step
3. Add an Array modifier to the vert. It's important to use constant offset, because the vert has no dimension so relative won't work.
4. Add a curve modifier to the Vert (using the created curve).
5. Add "Instancing" to the Vert. Now all the arrayed vert will replaced with the child object, the step (you can hide the original if you want).

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. Instancing worked like a charm for exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have almost 1000 hours in Blender and almost never used instancing before.